# Capacitor sketch diagram?

Tags: capacitor

My project is...I would have a circuit which will be power by 12 v DC only when car engine is running. Then, in time t =5 secs, the capacitor will fully be charged while engine still running or maybe still running for 5 or 6 hrs....still then capacitor is full. Now, the main point..as soon as engine is OFF, the capacitor will be discharged which will activate a relay to turn on the load bulb connected to this relay as long as the charged is in the capacitor. Could any kindly sketch a diagram of this project. Thanks.[image][image][image]

Comment: Please do correct the given diagram.

Comment: So diagram is fine, now how do you work out the time the relay stays energized using the information I gave you in the other answer. Have a look at http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-long-does-it-take-to-discharge-a-capacitor

Comment: But sir...when engine is OFF, capacitor discharge and relays is energised. However, still confused with when engine is on..... current flows to capacitor as well as the relay which gets activated. I don't want this relay to activate during engine ON. It should be active only as soon as engine is OFF. Thanks.

Comment: Relay should not be active when engine is running or on. It should be active or energise only when engine is OFF.

Comment: Add a second relay controlled by the ignition, so when the key is on, that second relay is off...

Comment: Could you provide the corrected diagram from your side? Thanks.

Comment: New circuit diagram attached.. please kindly check.

Comment: What new circuit diagram, only the old one is there...

Comment: So, it is not a bulb you want to power, it is a door unlocking system, see https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/69981/10976

Answer (score 3):

Diagram in black will do what you want, if you explained it correctly, without any capacitor...

The other diagram shows what you need to do to your diagram, you do know the difference between the normally open and normally closed contacts ...
[image]

Comment: I didn't understand your first diagram??

Comment: Not much different to yours...

Comment: Confusing is that how to block the relay being activated when engine is on??? This part I can't make out the diagram.

Comment: When the ign os off, that relay is normally closed (as stated in Red), when the ign is on, the relay contacts are opened...

Comment: Latest diagram which I supposed to be all correct is now uploaded. please do correct me if I'm wrong again. Thanks.

Comment: @ThangTons just follow my diagram...

Comment: Please shows the complete diagram...

Comment: It seems you forget one important thing.....the relay should be active as long as charges on the capacitor are not full discharged when engine if off.. your given circuit how it would work without any capacitor???!!!

Comment: @ThangTons if you want the bulb "on" when the engine is "off" then what I drew works... If you don't understand what an "NC" relay does then you should check them out.

Comment: I just connect a capacitor 10 v 470 microfarad with a 9 volt supply DC. Just to check out for preventing measures. About 2 to 5 minutes, the capacitor is getting hotter and eventually burst out. Please explain why this happen as against the early discussion that capacitor can be kept as long as we want. Thanks.

Comment: Capacitor burst in 5 minutes!!! Don't understand why??

Comment: Only if you use the correct capacitor, this is the first mention of any specific value... You need to check out what type of capacitor is relevant and make sure you are using it correctly. Your questions now are into electrical design, not motor vehicle maintenance and repair...

Comment: I am using cylinder shape type capacitor. What actually refers to when you said 'correct capacitor'? How do I identify the correct one??

Comment: Did you just connect the capacitor across the battery? What do you think the current flow was? Do you think you may need to limit the current flow, both during charge and discharge cycles? Will the relay coil help during the discharge cycles?

Comment: Yes I just connect only the capacitor in the circuit with position side to positive of the battery and negative of capacitor to the negative of battery respect. No resistor were used.

Comment: The most likely reason is that you connected the capacitor with the wrong polarity. usually the - terminal is marked clearly. If you connect a 10V cap to a 9V supply the wrong way round, you were lucky if survived as long as 5 minutes, and didn't explode covering everything (including you!) with corrosive gunk.

Comment: @alephzero so I assume you mean electrolytic for the 'exploding gunk" ones... not ceramic...